# Scala multi-level pattern matching

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I'm stuck with multi-level pattern matching, in the code below I want to match one particular case which is checked at several levels "cfe is Assignment, assignmentCfe.getRight is BinaryExpression, and so on", the solution looks ugly and I hope there is something better Scala can offer me. :)

```
  def findAll(cfg: Cfg, consumer: Consumer[Violation]): Unit = {
    val fa = new FlowAnalyzer
    val states = fa.analyze(cfg)

    states.foreach { case (cfe, state) => cfe match {
      case assign: Assignment => assign.getRight match {
        case expression: BinaryExpression => expression.getOperator match {
          case Operator.Div | Operator.Rem => processDivisions()
          case _ =>
        }
        case _ =>
      }
      case _ =>
    }
    case _ =>
    }
  }
```

How to get rid of these empty default cases in the end?

Another approach would be using nested conditions, but IntelliJ IDEA offers me to replace these conditions back to pattern matching

```
states.foreach { case (cfe, state) => if (cfe.isInstanceOf[Assignment]) {
      val assignment = cfe.asInstanceOf[Assignment]
      if (assignment.getRight.isInstanceOf[BinaryExpression]) {
        val expression = assignment.getRight.asInstanceOf[BinaryExpression]
        if (expression.getOperator == Operator.Div || expression.getOperator == Operator.Rem) processDivisions()
      }
    }}
```

Comment: What is the type of `states`?  It seems like you could be using `.filter` here in a lot of places.

Comment: @Tyler states is Map[Cfe, State] Cfe could be a lot of different things. Do I have to "cast" my entries somehow after filtering?

Comment: We can't really help without the exact definition of each one of these data structures. By they way it all is written, seems that you are just using matches instead of isInstanceOfs (exact of the Div | Rem part). This makes me ask, is pattern match really the tool you want? If these are case classes why aren't you matching all these with the nested values?

Comment: @pedrofurla Div | Rem is the most inner condition, I've updated my question so you can what I'm trying to match.

Comment: I prefer your second solution a lot. Don't get me wrong, I still think it's a abomination, but at least it is easy to read and quickly understand. You are dealing with type Unit everywhere, and leak  isInstanceOfs, don't try to pretend it's functional code, which is the purpose of match/cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are `Assignment` and `BinaryExpression` themselves case classes? Or do they have corresponding unapply methods? If so, then you can nest pattern matches and ignore fields you don't care about. For example, something like:

```
def findAll(cfg: Cfg, consumer: Consumer[Violation]): Unit = {
  val fa = new FlowAnalyzer
  val states = fa.analyze(cfg)

  states.foreach {
    case (Assignment(_, BinaryExpression(_, _, Operator.Div | Operator.Rem)), _) => processDivisions()
    case _ =>
  }
}
```

This will at least cut the number of default matches down to 1.

If these are not case classes or don't have extractors, then you could consider writing your own if this is a common enough (anti)pattern in your code: http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/extractor-objects.html

Comment: They are not, in fact they come from another module written in Java, but the look of you example is exactly what I'm looking for, so I will consider writing extractors to integrate with that Java code better.

Answer (score 0):

One other idea is you could use the "pimp my library" pattern to define an implicit conversion from any object into a class that can do a kind of partial matching:

```
class PartialMatcher[A](a: A) {
  def partialMatch(f: PartialFunction[A, Unit]): Unit = if (f.isDefinedAt(a)) f(a)
}
implicit def makePartialMatcher[A](a: A) = new PartialMatcher(a)
```

Then just replace all of those matches with `partialMatch`:

```
  def findAll(cfg: Cfg, consumer: Consumer[Violation]): Unit = {
    val fa = new FlowAnalyzer
    val states = fa.analyze(cfg)

    states.foreach { case (cfe, state) => cfe partialMatch {
      case assign: Assignment => assign.getRight partialMatch {
        case expression: BinaryExpression => expression.getOperator partialMatch {
          case Operator.Div | Operator.Rem => processDivisions()
        }
      }
    }}
  }
```

Note that there are other reasons why you might avoid this kind of thing... overusing implicit conversions can make understanding code a lot more difficult. It's a stylistic choice.

Comment: Something is missing here? I've added PartialMatcher and switched to your code, but have reports on partialMatch

Answer (score 0):

Use `.collect`:

```
def findAll(cfg: Cfg, consumer: Consumer[Violation]): Unit = {
  val fa = new FlowAnalyzer
  val states = fa.analyze(cfg)
  states.collect { case (assign: Assignment, _) => 
    assign.getRight
  }.collect { case expression: BinaryExpression => 
    expression.getOperator
  }.collect { case Operator.Div | Operator.Rem => 
    processDivisions
  }
```

Comment: I can't access "assign" in processDivisions this way.

Comment: Of course, you can't. It's defined outside of it, and you are not passing it in.